# Multiple conditions before executing function

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmousemove

I call this function I have getMouseXY, whenever the mouse moves. Works great for tracking this element with the mouse. Like so:

```
document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;
```

But I'd like to layer in some logic, so it's only when the mouse is over this one element AND the mouse is moving. I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
document.getElementById("circle1").onmouseover && document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;
```

Any ideas? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
document.getElementById("circle1").addEventListener('mousemove', getMouseXY);
```

which will fire whenever the mouse moves over the element with the ID `#circle1`

[**AWESOME FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wsu8Lbtn/1/)